# Can't find any device when boot up to the Linux kernel which I just built

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I built a Linux kernel bzImage incluing a rootfs, kernel version is 3.18.35. Then I use grub to boot the bzImage on another machine. I can successfully login the system and see the command line. Somehow, I can't see any sda* / sdb* devices under /dev. When I plug in a USB stick I can see below messages:

> usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
>
> usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
>
> usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
>
> usb 1-1: Product: USB DISK
>
> usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Viking Interworks
>
> usb 1-1: SerialNumber: VIKING000000109

But is still doesn't show up any device like sda or sdb. I can only see following devices:

> ls /dev
>
> console log null pts shm

The console and null devices are created in my rootfs.

Anyone who knows what happened to the kernel? Is there a configuration error when I compile the kernel? When I do the configuration, The onlything I changed is to set the initramfs to my rootfs directory.

BTW, I run dmesg and see lots of these failure messages:

> pci 0000:00:15.5: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x1000]
>
> pci 0000:00:15.5: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]
>
> pci 0000:00:15.4: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x1000]
>
> pci 0000:00:15.4: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]
>
> pci 0000:00:15.3: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x1000]
>
> pci 0000:00:15.3: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]

and this message:

> pci 0000:00:07.3: can't clain BAR 13 [io 0x1000-0x103f]: address conflict with ACPI PM1a_EVT_BLK [io 0x1000-0x1003]

Comment: You may get better luck at http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com.  This isn't really a programming problem, but rather a system admin issue.

Comment: Good show, improving  your Q, but agree that this is probably more appropriate to http://unix.stackexchange.com. Sorry that I can't help. This is beyond my experience. Good luck.

Comment: You have different issues here. A) to make sure you have `sd_mod` module either compiled in or as module, and check what userspace helper does in your case, for example udev. B) the PCI device 15 has a conflicting functions, basically has a bogus BAR configuration. WTF BAR 13?! There only possible to have 6 BARs for resources.

Comment: Finally I fixed the BAR 13 failure by set CONFIG_PHYSICAL_ALIGN=0x200000. But I still can't see any devices under /dev, could be my rootfs problem.